# updates can’t be installed because of too little diskspace on /boot

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage, software-updates

I'm new to Ubuntu and am running 14.04 on a Lenovo notebook. I can't install updates because there is not enough diskspace on /boot. When I try "sudo apt-get clean" in the terminal, nothing happens. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have unused kernels in `/boot`. Generally you only need at most two kernels there: the one you're currently running, and the one that you're installing. Once you've upgraded to a new kernel and you've rebooted to it and you know it works, you can remove older kernels. The packaging system tends to err on the side of caution and risks filling up the disk rather than leaving you with an unbootable system.

Try the command

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Watch what it says. Depending on how the system was installed, on what package management tools you used, and on the version of Ubuntu, it may offer to remove old kernels, and it may offer to remove other packages that you want to keep. If there's any package in here that you aren't sure about, say No. If there's a package that you know you want to keep, run `sudo apt-mark manual PACKAGENAME` and then `apt-get autoremove` won't offer to remove that package name anymore.

If the automatic method doesn't work for you, generate the list of kernel image packages to remove explicitly. You need to keep the running kernel and the latest version. The following shell command lists the installed `linux-image` packages (these are the packages that take up space in `/boot`), omitting the latest version (last line after sorting) and the running version (obtained with `uname -r`).

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${Package}\n' | sort -V | sed '$d' |grep -vx linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

If you don't want to keep the latest version (because you're going to install an even newer version anyway), only the running version, you can shrink this to

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${Package}\n' | grep -vx linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

You can remove these packages, as well as the matching header packages if you have them installed.

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg-query -W -f '${Package}\n' | sort -V | sed '$d' |grep -vx linux-image-$(uname -r) | sed 'p; s/image/headers/')
```

See also [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot) on our sister site [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), which proposes similar methods.